# what is the best way to host a BING map inside a page on Sharepoint 2010 Farm Solution?

Tags: 2010, javascript

I'm new to SharePoint, and could really use some advice:

- what is the best way to host a BING map inside Sharepoint ?

The task I have is: to host a bing map inside a Sharepoint 2010 Farm Solution.
We need to be able to overlay an ESRI type grid:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid

The data in the grid is sensitive, so would need to avoid transmitting the data back to the BING map server.

My current idea is:

- use javascript to host the bing map in a SharePoint page
- separately, read ESRI data from datasource, and overlay that over the bing map 
  (avoiding transmitting an ESRI data to bing)
- Does this sound practical with SharePoint 2010 ?
- Have you performed a similar project, and how would you go about it ?

thanks very much

Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can point you into the right direction!

doesnt need explaining as its well explained in detail:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81359/Bing-Maps-in-SharePoint-2010-Web-Part

using javascript:
http://andrewwhitten.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/use-bing-maps-as-a-dashboard-visualization-in-sharepoint-2010/

http://summit7systems.com/blogs/integrating-sharepoint-and-bing-maps/

adding pushpin to maps
http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/09/28/bing-maps-adding-and-tracking-pushpins-using-javascript.aspx

another good guide with java methods:
http://cm-bloggers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/using-microsoft-bing-maps-in-sharepoint.html

esri and sharepoint 
http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/mapping-sharepoint/download

**EDIT**
also like to note that someone wanted to do somthing similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549186/custom-zoomable-images-using-bing-maps

These should help you out and get you going.

Comment: no problem glad I can help :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following solution for SharePoint 2010:

- Create custom field for storing location information (latitude and longitude coordinates in decimal degrees) - Geolocation column
- Create new view type for List - Map view. A map view is a SharePoint view that displays a map (with data obtained from the  Maps service ), using longitude and latitude entries from the Geolocation field type

Actually this is how the location and map functionality is implemented in SharePoint 2013, but the good news is that it is possible now in **SharePoint 2010**. Follow [this article](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/06/24/integrating-location-and-map-functionality-in-sharepoint-2010/) and [project](https://github.com/vgrem/SP.Maps) for details.

---

### Some examples

1. Create item with location information (Geolocation column)
   [image]
2. Display form with Geolocation column for Contacts list
   [image]
3. Representing Geolocation column in a list view
   [image]
4. Completed map list view
   [image]

### Links

[Integrating location and map functionality in SharePoint 2010](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/06/24/integrating-location-and-map-functionality-in-sharepoint-2010/)

[SharePoint 2010 Maps](https://github.com/vgrem/SP.Maps) project is hosted on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Silverlight to create Bing Maps and host the XAP file in SharePoint 2010. SharePoint 2010 has a  Silverlight  webpart which takes the url of the xap file created from a silverlight application and shows it in the sharepoint 2010 pages. You may find this link useful to get started.
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2011/08/bing-maps-in-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: thanks for that - I think this is the simplest way, but hoping to avoid Silverlight as customer sees it as old technology

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at the solution we have developed in the company I work for:

http://www.vialutions.com/296/