# Visualize KML file data in SharePoint

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, kml-files

We got geodata as **KML files** ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language)).

**Is there a way to visualize this data in SharePoint 2016 on premise?**

As the files hold interna we would like to avoid loading the files to a public platform and add this as iFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google search gives you a few promised solutions that might or might not fit your needs. But you might have to do it the hard way, which involves custom code.

First you might have to transform your KML some more other format (e.g. GeoJson), e.g. with help of [Ogre (ogr2ogr web client)](https://ogre.adc4gis.com/) or [SharpKML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpKml.Core/).

Then use a map solution for SharePoint - there are [many](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43601/what-is-the-best-way-to-host-a-bing-map-inside-a-page-on-sharepoint-2010-farm-so). Or just code your [open layers](http://openlayers.org/) map view displaying your GeoJson.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The hint with "GeoJson" was very valuable - as well as the link to the StackExchange post. My attempts to "google" a solution seem to have failed due to the word "KML" as there seems not to be direct solution. Thanks a lot! Marked as answer and voted!